# While Loops: my program is intended to show growth of a bank account with user input

Tags: python-3.x

1. This is my code.

   ```
   iBal = int(input('Enter your initial balance: '))
   aPer = int(input('Enter an annual interest percentage: '))
   fBal = int(input('Enter your desired final balance: '))
   sum1 = iBal*(1 + aPer/100)

   while sum1 < fBal:
       print(format(sum1, '.2f'))
       sum1 = iBal*(1+aPer/100)
       iBal = sum1

   print(format(iBal, '.2f'))
   ```
2. This is what's returned, with user input (iBal=500, aPer=4, fBal=550)

   ```
   >>>520.00
   >>>520.00
   >>>540.80
   >>>562.43
   ```
3. I need the first 520.00 to be 500.00 (the original inital balance entered), anyone see my mistake? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, in a simplier way (your code is fine and correct too):

```
sum1 = iBal

while sum1 < fBal:
    print(format(sum1, '.2f'))
    sum1 = sum1 * (1 + aPer / 100.0)

print(format(sum1, '.2f'))
```

The way above is more readable, but if you want it even more concise, you can only use `iBal` and not `sum1`:

```
while iBal < fBal:
    print(format(iBal, '.2f'))
    iBal = iBal * (1 + aPer / 100.0)

print(format(iBal, '.2f'))
```

Answer (score 0):

And you cant get 500 as output in the first case because you did not print out initial balance iBal before making calculations.